# Is this way of defining \section in Plain TeX correct?

Tags: sectioning, plain-tex

I am relatively new to Plain T<sub>E</sub>X and I wanted to define a `\section` command to typeset a bold and centered text with some spacing around it.
Here is what I came up with.

```tex
\def\section#1{\bigbreak\centerline{\bf #1}\medskip\nobreak}
```

Is that a correct way to do so? In particular I don't know if `\medskip` has to be typed before or after `\nobreak`. I know that the `\beginsection` macro (that left aligns the section title) is more complex than that but I don't understand what benefits it has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the penalty before the skip otherwise you can ge a break:

[image]

```
\def\section#1{\bigbreak\centerline{\bf #1}\medskip\nobreak}

\def\text{Aaaa bbb ccc one two three four five.
Red blue green yellow white black. }


\text\text
\section{1 abc}
\text\text

\section{2 aabbcc}
\text\text

\vskip 40\baselineskip

\text

\section{3 aa}

\text\text

\bye
```

If you swap them round you get

[image]

Other than that, apart from using a centered box and a braced argument rather that `\par` delimited, it is more or less similar to the plain tex macro.

The main thing missing is control of indentation of the following paragraph, but perhaps you want indented first paragraphs anyway.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I don't need to control the indentation so it's perfect

Comment: What else is missing is a |\mark| etc...

Comment: @YiannisLazarides missing from a real section macro, but not mising compared with `\beginsection` which also doesn't do marks (not that I'd ever consider plain tex for a real document other than test examples that it is designed for)